# Is there a generally accepted way to immediately get data from a mysql database upon loading a .jsp file?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp, server

I'm new to JSP and web development in general so I'm wondering what the best way of achieving this would be.

At the moment, I just check for a url parameter and if the parameter "db_data" is null, then I redirect to a servlet, grab the data from the database and store it as I need it, then I redirect to the previous .jsp file with a ?db_data=true url parameter added on.

```
//pseudocode
if(request.getparam(db_data) == null)
{
    redirect_to(blahblahmyservlet);
}
```

But I feel like this is a pretty unefficient way to achieve what I'm looking for.  Is there a better / more accepted way of trying to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Many different ways to do what you are asking

- Your way (maybe use core el tags)
- Servlet Filters
- Do not call jsp directly (use request dispatcher model)

You may consider looking at a MVC framework e.g. struts, stripes or spring mvc

-- Use of EL

```
<c:if test="${sessionScope.db_data == null}">
<c:redirect url="GetDataServlet" />
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use MVC approach to implement such functionality. Where JSP serves as a View component just to show information without any logic. Servlet checks db_data parameter then does redirect/forward to the particluar JSP page. You can use session to put all needed info that can be shown in JSP.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a friendly way, you should use Spring MVC or other database middleware to operate the database, which is much more flexible and easy to expand.

Comment: You can find the answer on the Spring.io. I had to use JPA to operate the database, it is very convenient, can be found below in the Spring Data Spring JPA.

Answer (score 0):

one approach is , directly rediret from index.jsp to servlet,at servlet side check your parameter and decide where to move.if parameter satisfy your requirement then directly move ,otherwise move with db operation.